# how to import data from DBF to SQL using SQL script?

Tags: sql, odbc, oledb, dbf, dbase

I am trying to import data from DBF file to SQL table using the following command -

```
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL', 
'Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DBQ=E:\data\;',
'select * from E:\data\a.dbf')
```

But it is failing saying

```
    OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x120 Thread 0x3084 DBC 0x303dfbc Xbase'.".    
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Disk or network error.".    
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1    
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".
```

Any clue why it is giving error? For the second error I have given full access to temp folder as suggested by some blog. Still it is showing both error.

Comment: http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm

Answer (score 3):

If filename is a `.dbf`
Try this:

```
select * from
openrowset('MSDASQL',
'Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=E:\Data;',
'SELECT * FROM a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT is specifying the path to the file - you should be specifying the table name instead, which is presumably 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement CodeByMoonlight, the Driver information points to the path the data file is found, so then your subsequent query should only be "Select * should from a" since both the path and the .dbf extension should be implied

Answer (score 1):

You are using 64-bit SQL Server which is looking to the 64-bit ODBC sources when the drivers are 32-bit.  There is a workaround for FoxPro (also DBF) that should work for dBASE as well:

Open a new SqlDataSource in Visual Studio using the .NET Framework Provider for OLE DB then MS OLE DB Provider for VFP. The connection string should look like this (or with UNC)

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=h:\Programs\Data;Persist Security Info=True;User    ID=Your_user;Password=your_password
```

The config wizard includes a part to test your SQL.  You can use this run ad hoc SQL.